# Trouble with Microsoft Word connection point sink example / MFC

Tags: c++, com, mfc, connection-points

I've been trying to implement a connection point sink for a third party COM component using MFC.  I've developed some COM components before, though connection point sinks is not something I'm well versed in.  After banging my head against a wall for a while, I decided to go back to basics and found this Microsoft example:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/183599

It seemed the most similar to what I'm trying to do.  I attempted to reproduce the example exactly as described.  Although my MS Word version is 2010, the referenced interfaces still appear to be valid.  I dutifully followed the instructions, literally cutting and pasting the code into my own project and only having to make adjustments for wide character strings.  After compile, I can launch the word app and quit it, but I don't receive the connection point events, which after all was the whole point.  I thought perhaps the problem was with the function dispid, so I attempted to add DISP_FUNCTION_ID entries into the Dispatch Map; but that just leads to an assertion on oledisp1.ccp line 549 which turns out to be in the CCmdTarget::GetStackSize function.

I'm sure this is dumb simple, but I just can't get it to work.  Can somebody please help me figure out what is missing from the example? Thanks.

Comment: If you're having difficulty understanding COM connection points, you should read [An introduction to COM connection points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/12/10424940.aspx). Also potentially relevant here is [Dispatch interfaces as connection point interfaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/12/10425215.aspx).

Comment: Not having trouble understanding connection point concepts.  I'm having trouble getting it to work using recommended MFC approach whereby a  CCmdTarget derived class is used to implement the sink interface. It seems straight forward, the example makes perfect sense to me, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I was on the right track adding the DISP_FUNCTION_ID macros to my Dispatch map, however I had stupidly used VT_VOID instead of VT_EMPTY which was caused the runtime assertion.